# Select all rows that have ID in top (10)

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables:

```
Person: PersonId, Name
PersonAddress: PersonAddressId, PersonId, Street
```

A person can have multiple addresses.

Do a left join on `PersonId` and filter for `Name`, e.g., `like '%john%'`.

Now I get a number of rows. And I only need the top 10 persons (by id) what could make up 20 rows if each has 2 addresses. And I need that 20 rows.

What is the best way to do that?

```
Select...
Where PersonId IN (Select distinct personId ...)
```

Or use `Over` to maybe count on changing ids?

The real tables have more columns and more joins.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the top 10 before the `join`.  Let me assume you are using SQL Server or a related database that uses `top`:

```
select p.*, . . .
from (select top (10) p.*
      from person p
      where name like '%john%'
      order by id
     ) p left join
     personaddress pa
     on pa.PersonId = p.PersonId;
```